# What are the options available for Doctrine's Doctrine_Core::generateModelsFromDb method?

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

Doctrine 1.2 has a method called generateModelFromDb, [documented here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/Doctrine_Core/1_2#method_generatemodelsfromdb), that generates model files for all of the tables in a database.

This function accepts an optional third parameter with an array of "options" to use when generating models, the specifics of which are not documented. What options are available for me to specify here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The complete list with default values from Doctrine/Import/Schema:

```
protected $_options = array('packagesPrefix'        =>  'Package',
                            'packagesPath'          =>  '',
                            'packagesFolderName'    =>  'packages',
                            'suffix'                =>  '.php',
                            'generateBaseClasses'   =>  true,
                            'generateTableClasses'  =>  false,
                            'generateAccessors'     =>  false,
                            'baseClassPrefix'       =>  'Base',
                            'baseClassesDirectory'  =>  'generated',
                            'baseClassName'         =>  'Doctrine_Record');
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Doctrine1.2.4 -

There are a few missing from that list - and they are important ones!

```
'pearStyle'             => true,
'classPrefix'           => '',
'classPrefixFiles'      => false,
```

I used this when generating my classes for a Zend Framework project, example script:

```
<?php

/**
 * Doctrine CLI script
 */

define('APPLICATION_ENV', 'development');

define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/Doctrine'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/config/default.ini'
);

$application->getBootstrap()->bootstrap('doctrine');

Doctrine::generateModelsFromDb(
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/default/models/DbTable', 
    array('db1'),
    array(
        'pearStyle'            => true,
        'generateTableClasses' => true,
        'baseClassesDirectory' => '',
        'classPrefix'=> 'Model_DbTable_',
        'classPrefixFiles' => false,
        'baseClassPrefix' => 'Generated_'
     )
);
```

Comment: Sure glad I posted this... Forgot where I put this info, needed it again! :)

Answer (score 0):

The best I've seen is this:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/ru/defining-models

... where you can try glean off the page any data type-specific "options". I haven't come across anything more comprehensive than that. The API documentation seems to assume that it's obvious what the possible options are.

Answer (score 0):

This looks promicing:
from [here](http://trac.doctrine-project.org/browser/branches/1.0/docs/manual/de/utilities/facade.txt?rev=4979)

```
 // Generate your models from an existing database
 Doctrine::generateModelsFromDb('/path/to/generate/models', array('connection_name'),   $options);

 // Array of options and the default values
 $options = array('packagesPrefix'        =>  'Package',
                  'packagesPath'          =>  '',
                  'packagesFolderName'    =>  'packages',
                  'suffix'                =>  '.php',
                  'generateBaseClasses'   =>  true,
                  'baseClassesPrefix'     =>  'Base',
                  'baseClassesDirectory'  =>  'generated',
                  'baseClassName'         =>  'Doctrine_Record');
```